# ADF remove required asterisk

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a `panelLabelAndMessage` containing `inputComboboxListOfValues` and `outputText`. The LOV is a mandatory field and hence it has the asterisk beside it. But I have changed `simple` property to true as  I did not want to show label of LOV ans assigned the same label to `panelLabelAndMessage`. Also changed `showrequired` property to true for the asterisk. But now the LOV field is also showing asterisk which is undesirable. Any way to remove the star mark but still have the **model level validation** in place.

I do not want to use `required` property of LOV.

The code for my label and fields is as below.

```
<af:panelLabelAndMessage label="#{bindings.Department.label}"
                             id="plam1"
                             showRequired="#{bindings.Department.hints.mandatory}">
      <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="horizontal">
        <af:inputComboboxListOfValues id="DepartmentId"
                                      popupTitle="Search and Select: #{bindings.DepartmentId.hints.label}"
                                      value="#{bindings.DepartmentId.inputValue}"
                                      model="#{bindings.DepartmentId.listOfValuesModel}"
                                      columns="#{bindings.DepartmentId.hints.displayWidth}"
                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.DepartmentId.hints.tooltip}"
                                      required="#{bindings.DepartmentId.hints.mandatory}"
                                      autoSubmit="true"
                                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.BackingBean.departmentLov}"
                                      valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.BackingBean.onSelectDepartment}">
          <f:validator binding="#{bindings.DepartmentId.validator}"/>
          <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                            pattern="#{bindings.DepartmentId.format}"/>
        </af:inputComboboxListOfValues>
        <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s1"/>
        <af:outputText value="#{bindings.DepartmentName.inputValue}" id="ot1"
                     partialTriggers="DepartmentId"

                       binding="#{backingBeanScope.BackingBean.DepartmentName}"/>
      </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer to core question (can you remove the asterisk ): Yes, by using ADF Skinning.
Some examples:

```
.hideRequired af|selectOneChoice::label af|panelFormLayout::label-cell .AFRequiredIconStyle,
.hideRequired af|panelFormLayout::label-cell .AFRequiredIconStyle,
.hideRequired af|selectOneChoice::label .AFRequiredIconStyle 
{ 
    display:none ;
}
```

Note that we add *hideRequired* as a styleClass to the component (you can give it an other name). 
The one you will probably need to use is:

```
.hideRequired af|inputComboboxListOfValues::label .AFRequiredIconStyle 
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way apart from using Skinning or stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `required` property, the validation will still fire for LOV. 
But since you have `skipValidtion` set to `true` therefore the model level validation will also not fire.

Here is how you implement required field validation without using required="true" or model level validation in Jdeveloper 11.1.2.* or higher, as this solution does not works for versions older than JSF2.0

Create a validator method in your managed bean, or if you want to reuse the validator then create a custom validator for your application.

```
public void requiredFieldValidator(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object) {
    if (null == object) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "This field can not be empty",
                                                      null));
    }
    else{
        if(object.toString().trim().equals("")){
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "This field can not be empty",
                                                          null));
        }
    }
}
```

Use this method as your lov validator

```
<af:inputListOfValues label="Lov1" popupTitle="Search and Result Dialog" id="ilov1"
                                      validator="#{pageFlowScope.mBean.emailValidator}"/>
```

More importantly, to make validator works on empty fields, set `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` to true in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Attribute level validation does not fire when we remove `required` property

Comment: <f:validator binding="#{bindings.DepartmentId.validator}"/> should execute, irrespective of whether required is set to true or not.

Comment: When are you expecting the validation to fire? Is there a button which submits the form, which LOV is part of? Also, are validation on other components getting fired?

Comment: Yes all other validations are firing on click OK button. But my **taskflow page defination** file has `SkipValidation` set to `true` as I am not submitting the complete form yet.

Comment: the validation is failing when i remove requires and it is passing on to next screen with null values.

Comment: Ah, validation is not firing because you have `SkipValidation` set to `true`. One other way to enable validation on LOV is to check for LOV value before navigating to other page and if the value is null, show a popup with the required field error message.

Comment: But that will not provide the same look and feel.

Comment: But `skipvalidation` has nothing to do about required validations. it is only for skipping model level validations. The required validation must fire irrespective of `skipvalidation` set to true or false